# Logitech G29: Physical Maximum in HID Device Descriptor is to little

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I am using a Raspberry Pi (linux kernel 4.4) and "libusb" to read the steering angle of a Logitech G29 HID Device (PS3 mode). I get only one byte of data for the angle and that is far to little for the steering range of +-450° deg. The HID Device Descriptor shows the problem.

> Item(Global): Physical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x00 ] 255

How could I change the Physical Maximum to 65535?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that a number from 0 to 255 cannot be used to represent angles between -450 and +450?  Isn't it possible that a value of 0 corresponds to -450 degrees and a value of 255 corresponds to 455 degrees?  It's very unlikely that Logitech made a fatal design flaw in the HID interface of their device.

If you really want to change the HID interface, then, at a minimum, you would have to reprogram the firmware of your G29 device in order to change that descriptor and change the HID report it describes.  It is very likely that the device is closed source and that there are no instructions for reprogramming the firmware, so you are probably out of luck.  Adding more resolution to that measurement might also require hardware changes, which could be difficult.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It don't make sense to splitt a angle range of 900deg in only 256 pieces. So the resulution is 3,51deg/per step... and to use one byte for -450deg and another byte for +450 don't make sense either (res. 1.75deg/p s). Because if you use two bytes as complement you will get a resulution of 0.01373 and this is acceptable. You want to do this 2^8 + 2^8 = 512 and the normal way is to do this 2^8 * 2^8 = 65536 (Two's complement). I don't want to change the Lg firmware, I want to configure the HID device driver in linux.

Comment: Either you are looking at the wrong part of the HID descriptor and there is some higher-resolution field that reports the steering, or the device actually reports the steering with 8-bit resolution and you just have to live with that.  It's really unlikely that you will be able to change the firmware or hardware of a consumer device like this.